# How to set rule in Laravel for zero value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

How to check incoming value on the zero value: `0`, `"0"`.

If it is zero then return validation false?

I tried regexpes, but may be there is simplest method?

Comment: typecasting is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there isn't the possibility of the number being less than 0, this would probably be easiest:

```
'field' => 'numeric|min:1'
```

This would mean you could only accept numeric values (not strings), but it would force the value to not be 0. If you need to also accept strings, it may be easier to write a custom method, as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules).